# How to get the last record

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get my last record in the table
I use this code but it returns nothing

```
var a = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var student = db.tbl_farmers.OrderByDescending(s => s.id).FirstOrDefault();
dataGridView1.DataSource = student;
```

Comment: What do you mean by returns nothing? Are you saying student is null? is tbl_farmers not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In LINQ we achieve the same thing with the help of OrderByDescending function and Take function.**

```
var qry = db.ObjectCollection
                     .Where(m => m.<field> == data) 
                     .OrderByDescending(m => m.<field>) 
                     .Take(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var student = db.tbl_farmers.OrderByDescending(s => s.id).Take(1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = student;ode here
```